# Mongoose promise and sonarqube

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, sonarqube

I like the async await syntax, and I use it a lot with mongoose.

So in my project there is plenty of :

```
const user = await User.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
})
```

Which works just as expected. However, in sonarqube, I have these errors :
`Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise.`

And the sonarqube rule i :

> It is possible to use await on values which are not Promises, but it's 
>    useless and misleading. The point of await is to pause execution until 
>    the Promise's asynchronous code has run to completion. With anything 
>    other than a Promise, there's nothing to wait for.
>
> This rule raises an issue when an awaited value is guaranteed not to be a Promise.
>
> Noncompliant Code Example

```
let x = 42;
await x; // Noncompliant
```

> Compliant Solution

```
let x = new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
await x;

let y = p ? 42 : new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
await y;
```

I am using mongo 4.0 and mongoose 5.3.1

Since I can use the `.then`, `.catch` syntax I thought that I was dealing with promise so how could I fix that ?

Comment: The problem may be in how sonarqube is duck-typing the Query type.  From mongoose's own docs ["Mongoose queries are **not** promises"](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises), however they are `.then()`able and are compliant with `async/await` so you may be getting a false positive.

Comment: Not sure. But use `.exec` with the above query and see what happens.`const user = await User.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
}).exec()
` Because mongoose queries are not full-fledged promises and `.exec`  help  to make it real promise.

Comment: @Fanpark by the way your solution fixed my issue so if you mind posting it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do not know much about `SonarQube`. I just figured out `SonarQube` is tool to check the code quality and get that it required `await` only prefix with the `promises` and there `mongoose` fails even having `.then`.

Mongoose queries do not return "fully-fledged" promise even they have `.then()`. So in order to get "fully-fledged" promise you need to use `.exec()` function.

```
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments its a false positive, more accurately a depricated warning.

You can either ignore it or add this to your code right after the import statement:

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```